# Alterar cor de objeto SVG com animação

Tags: html, svg

Utilisando a tag animateColor, queria alterar a cor de um objeto SVG. Exemplo jsfiddle mas não funciona:

```
<svg width="500" height="650" >
<rect ry=5 rx=0 x=150 y=100 width=90 height=100 style="fill:red">
    <animateColor attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" 
        from="#ffd700" 
        to="lightblue"  
        dur="5s"
    /> 
</rect>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b577jhd9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O elemento `animateColor` que você usou [foi descontinuado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateColor) por ser redundante com o elemento [`animate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate), que funciona:

```html
    <svg width="500" height="650" >
    <rect ry=5 rx=0 x=150 y=100 width=90 height=100 style="fill:red">
        <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" 
            from="#ffd700" 
            to="lightblue"  
            dur="5s"
        /> 
    </rect>
    </svg>
```